# Cloud PubSub Java Parallel Acknowledgements

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub

It looks like the Java client for Google Cloud pubsub does not support batch acknowledgments: you need to call `ack` on each message individually.

I was wondering if acknowledging messages in parallel is supported? is the client thread-safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java client is thread safe, yes. You can call ack on many messages in parallel. The library itself will batch these acks back to the server for efficiency when it can.